# Return FCM Token to store in a variable (Swift 5 with Firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the FCM Token as a variable from the current user so I can write it into their Firestore document. This is the code I'm using to retrieve the token, which works:

```
var fcmToken = ""

    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
             print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
             } else if let result = result {
                  fcmToken = setFCMToken(result.token)
        }
    })
//use fcmToken variable here to write data in user document. Value getting sent is just initial declaration of ""
    func setFCMToken(_ token:String) -> String{
        print(token)
        return token
    }
```

But the fcmToken variable is not updating. I believe my problem might be with scope. I'm not sure how to get around this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, seems a bit extra but it works:

```
    //Initial declaration at top of class above ViewDidLoad
    var fcmToken = ""

    //In ViewDidLoad
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
                } else if let result = result {
                self.fcmToken = result.token
                self.setFCMToken(self.fcmToken)
            }
        })


    //Where ever you need to access token as variable
    let token = self.getFCMToken()

    //bottom of VC
    func setFCMToken(_ token:String){
        print(token)
        self.fcmToken = token
    }
    
    func getFCMToken() -> String{
        return self.fcmToken
        
    }
```